# A simple SQL problem: Making an SQL insert statement with text string that contain ' characters

Tags: c#, sql

I follow the syntax of

```
INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES (value1, value2, value3…)
```

This has worked fine so far. But now I have some values that contain normal English text like "I'm going home". The ' character ruins the SQL command in C#. I have written the following:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Bio VALUES ('" + name + "','"I'm going home" + "');
```

evaluates to

```
INSERT INTO Bio VALUES ('Peter','I'm going home')
```

which obviously will not work. How do I make sure special character will not ruin the SQL statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SqlParameter` for heaven's sake. Otherwise your program will be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It will also solve your problem with the special characters.

Comment: In addition to that, parameterized queries are more likely to benefit from optimization - precompiling, server side caching, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This is the obvious answer.

Answer (score 4):

Learn about parameterized queries for your provider. They exists for Odbc, OleDb, Sql, etc.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Bio Values (@name, @text)";
command.Parameters.Add(/* appropriate param type for your provider */); // add for @name, @text, etc.
// execute query
```

Comment: I have used them before. But now I understand their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use two single quotes whenever there is a single quote you want to escape

Also instead of building your queries like this, you should use parameterized queries in a language of your choice. Escaping the characters yourself opens the door for SQL Injections.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can escape a single quote by screening with another one.
For example the following is a valid statement

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Column1) VALUES ('Hello I''m Jack');
```

However I suggest you using parameters.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Bio VALUES (@Name, @OtherValue)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("OtherValue", "I'm going home");
```

One addition point in favor of using parameters is that you are free from burden of formatting and other stuff. I mean date values, uniqueidentifiers, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I do use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text)
```

It makes all that SQL injection stuff disappear, and it seems easier than to use parameters.
Don't forget to use

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text)
```

to get your input back in the form you received it

Comment: See [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Parameters are not difficult - look at @Anthony Pegram's example. If you find ADO.NET verbose, consider using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Comment: You destroy the purity of the data. Data must be independent from the application that is using it. First name `O'Connel` must be `O'Connel`, not `O&#39;Connel`. It further may be used by desktop application, queried via WSDL/REST API, aggregated and analyzedt, etc.